# Does Jquery UI tabs have an "after collapse" event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

What event can i use from jquery ui for identifying when a panel collapse has been completed(on the browser). I need to make some calculations on the basis of screen layout after the collapse. If i grab the select or the show even callbacks - i get the screen layout after the click but before the UI has been changed.

Anyone ?

Comment: Do you mean for an [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)?

Comment: Nope -  a collapsible tab. something like http://jsbin.com/icebe/127/edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can be notified after animation completed using `activate` event as described in the [jQuery UI doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate).

> If the tabs are collapsing, `ui.newTab` and `ui.newPanel` will be empty jQuery objects.

So you just have to check the length of `ui.newTab` and `ui.newPanel` to choose to do something or not.

```
.tabs({
    collapsible: true,
    activate: function(event, ui) {
        if (ui.newTab.length == 0 && ui.newPanel.length == 0) {
            // do something
        }
    }
});
```

[Here is the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3W6W/1/)